# Kendo Grid - Only edited rows are available for update in MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my application I am using Kendo grid and my code is as follows.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<nVisionGlobal.Application.Pricing.Models.FuelIndex>()
    .Name("FuelGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.FSCIndexID).Width(50).Sortable(false).ClientTemplate("<input class='check_row' type='checkbox'  data-clno = #= FSCIndexID # ></input>")
        .HeaderTemplate("<input id='check_all' type='checkbox'  > </input>");
        columns.Bound(p => p.EffectiveDate).Title("Effective From").Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}").Width(150);
        columns.Bound(p => p.NationalUsAvg).Title("US Average");
        columns.Bound(p => p.EastCoast).Title("East Coast");
        columns.Bound(p => p.NewEngland).Title("New England");
        columns.Bound(p => p.CentralAtlantic).Title("Central Atlantic");
        columns.Bound(p => p.LowerAtlantic).Title("Lower Atlantic");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Midwest).Title("Midwest");
        columns.Bound(p => p.GulfCoast).Title("Gulf Coast");
        columns.Bound(p => p.RockyMtn).Title("Rocky Mountain");
        columns.Bound(p => p.WestCoast).Title("West Coast");
        columns.Bound(p => p.California).Title("California");
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Destroy();
        }).Title("Commands").Width(200);
    })
    .AutoBind(false)
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create();
        toolbar.Save(); 
    })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Navigatable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(m => m.FSCIndexID);
            model.Field(m => m.FSCIndexID).Editable(false);
            model.Field(m => m.EffectiveDate).Editable(true);
        })
        .Create(create => create.Action("Inline_Create", "Fuel"))
        .Read(p => p.Action("FuelSearch", "Fuel").Type(HttpVerbs.Get).Data("FuelSearchInfo"))
        .Update("Inline_Update", "Fuel")
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("#", "Fuel"))
    )
    .Pageable()
)
```

As from the above code it is clear cells are editable (GridEditMode.InCell). I have a button control to save data. When I click on button only the edited data from rows(multiple row edit) will pass to the controller.

I have written the following jQuery to captured edited rows.

```
<script>
if ($(this).attr("href") === "Save" || $(this).attr("href") === "Update") {
            //alert('Ok')
            e.preventDefault();
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: "Inline_Create/Fuel",
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
               // charset='utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify($("#FuelGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.select())
        });
</script>
```

But the code is not working.

Comment: You can get JSON array from dataSource and post it back to server http://stackoverflow.com/a/36078364/1849455