# Kendo UI Remote DataSource Modification

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I have a Kendo DataSource that takes its data from a remote server (Json) and it bind the data to a kendo template in the client-side.

On the client, right now I just display the Data. However, I want to add/remove data in the dataSource as well. How can I send the dataSource after modification back to server and store it in there ?

Here is a good example of what I am trying to do. While this example reads its data from a local variable, would you please let me know:

**How can I store the dataSource on the server-side after user make modification on the client ?**

http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/D4g8S/

For example the add method just update the datasource on the client side. However, I want to send it to the Server and store it some how there. As a results, if someone else open the same web page in another client, he/she can see the changes as well.

```
$("#add").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     var $todo = $("input[name='description']");

     currentId += 1;
     dataSource.add({
     id: currentId,
     done: false,
     description: $todo.val()
     });

     $todo.val("");
     $todo.focus();
});
```

I am using C# .Net MVC on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you are asking how you can made server changes based on changes on client side? If is that true you can do three things:

- catch data which you modify (added, deleted, updated),
- Serialize to JSON,
- send to the controller's action.

Here is simple example how you can read data from your datasource:

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ] 
});

dataSource.fetch(function(){
    // reading data from dataSource
    var raw = dataSource.data();
    // entire dataSource
    alert("This is entire dataSource: " + JSON.stringify(raw)); 
    // this is what will be removed
    alert("This is removed: " + JSON.stringify(raw[0]));    
    dataSource.remove(raw[0]);          
    // this is what is rest
    alert("This is rest: " + JSON.stringify(raw));
});
```

After you assign these data to some object you can serialize into JSON with: JSON.stringify(data) method.

Than you can post these data to controller's action and do some work. How to post JSON to MVC controller is common question, please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370062/posting-json-data-via-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-4-controller-action).

For deleting and updating is similar. Basically you have to catch data which you want, serialize and post to action.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `add` method on the data source and specify there where to post the new data. There is an [example](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-add) in the KendoUI documentation. From there you can also configure the edit/remove methods.

Answer (score 1):

To get JSON array from dataSource object use [toJSON](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject#methods-toJSON) method

```
dataSource.data().toJSON()
```

then you can post it back to the server

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D4g8S/395/)